# Setting asynchronous value as a property value after Class instantiation

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like the value of one of the properties in my class to be an asynchronous value. It almost works; when you call `setTimeout`, `profile.songs` is in fact resolved with `Promise {<resolved>: Array(100)}`.

Except, I want the **value** (in this case, `Array(100)`) of the `Promise` to be the value of `property.songs`.

Edit: I should add some clarity to the question. The object must be instantiated synchronously i.e. `profile.toxicGarbageIsland` and `profile.spiceUpYourLife` are mandatory, and are required for the object to instantiate. The promise value, `profile.songs` however, is optional, and can come **after** the object is instantiated.

```
class Gojira {
  constructor (profile) {
    Object.assign(this, profile)
  }

  static init () {
    let profile = {};

    profile.toxicGarbageIsland = true;
    profile.spiceUpYourLife = false;
    profile.songs = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(function(response){
        return response.data;   
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })

    return new Gojira(profile);
  }
}


let gojiraInstance = Gojira.init();

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(gojiraInstance)
}, 2000)
```

N.B. I've removed the promise from the `constructor` to ensure it's only concern is with returning an object instance, which I've read is best practice.

Comment: `static init ()` -> `static async init ()`, `profile.songs =` -> `profile.songs = await`, and `let gojiraInstance = Gojira.init()` -> `Gojira.init().then(gojiraInstance => { ... })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think the reason this question is different is because it involves instantiating a new object that doesn't require async values to be immediately available.  Also, that answer, whilst very good, is a general overview of promises and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What you are doing is about right. Caching the promise is the correct thing to do. Don't be talked into caching the data delivered by the promise. That's just a recipe for uncertainty.

Comment: Also, don't forget to re-throw the caught error, otherwise the promise will deliver `undefined` down its success path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign the promise to `profile.songs` - instead, simply run the promise, and on resolution, assign the result to `profile.songs` and call the constructor.

```
static init() {
  let profile = {};

  profile.toxicGarbageIsland = true;
  profile.spiceUpYourLife = false;
  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function(response) {
      profile.songs = response.data;
      return new Gojira(profile);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
}
```

You'll also have to consume it asynchronously:

```
Gojira.init()
  .then(gojiraInstance => {
    // ...
  });
```

I'm assuming the constructor requires the `profile` to be fully set before running. If not, then allow the constructor to accept a `Promise` as a parameter as well, which then assigns the `songs` property on resolution, like this:

```
class Gojira {
  constructor (profile, songsPromise) {
    Object.assign(this, profile);
    if (songsPromise) songsPromise.then(({ data }) => this.songs = data);
  }
  static init () {
    const profile = {};
    profile.toxicGarbageIsland = true;
    profile.spiceUpYourLife = false;
    const songsPromise = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    return new Gojira(profile, songsPromise);
  }
}
const gojiraInstance = Gojira.init();
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(gojiraInstance)
}, 2000)
```

Comment: To that end, you could even initialize `profile` inside the `promise.then()` if you decide to do this

Comment: Actually, the constructor doesn't require `profile` to be fully set before running, only `profile.toxicGarbageIsland` and `profile.spiceUpYourLife` are mandatory. `profile.songs` is optional at the point of instantiation, because I don't want its absence to block the object from being created (and rendered on screen). I'm happy for `profile.songs` to come later.

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you clarify what you mean by " allow the constructor to accept a Promise as a parameter as well"?